# You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/3.0.0 directory

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sass, rubygems, preprocessor

I want to install sass in my Ubuntu Linux, I'm trying to install it using ruby, but then I got this output

```
haphoera@Xubuntu:~$ gem install sass-embedded
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/3.0.0 directory.
```

I've tried installing sass using npm or node.js but it gave me the same output, I already closed the terminal I've used for that, so I can't really show what's the error I'm receiving when installing sass using npm. But it's kind of the same with gem, it's about the permissions. I've watched videos on youtube to solve the npm problem but all of them are not working.

So I'm trying to use ruby instead (if it's better, because I read online that installing sass using npm is slower).

How can I change the permission or fix this? Can't find anything useful on the internet.

Comment: Use some manager of Ruby versions like asdf, rbenv, rvm, chruby instead of using system Ruby. Or use docker

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, try this: export GEM_HOME=~/projects/shared/gems/ruby/versionyouareusing/gems

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining where that code should go.